# database stores strange characters

Tags: php, postgresql

I have problem between frontend liferay portal with php portlet and database. To describe situation: 
I have a portlet - no matter what it does - which stores some strings to database. When I read the strings back to frontend every single "non-english" character is weird. I need to store a wide range of characters like Slovak, Czech, Polish, German, Romanian, etc.

I'm pretty sure the problem is not in the front end because before I store it (or in the same time) I display what am I storing in the frontend and string looks ok. So UTF-8 in frontend works. But when I look in the DB, everything is mixed and there are characters like `ÃÂ³` and other combinations of these funny characters.

My postgres database is also set to UTF-8. First I thought there is a connection with locales so I made every supported locale on my server working now. Still no help. I have one brute force solution to transform those characters to #xxxx; code but its real worky.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you need to make the connection UTF-8, I'm not pretty sure on this because I always worked on MySQL, but there, you need to actually do a: SET NAMES utf8 query

Comment: See the [last example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php#example-2087).

Comment: @aleation There's no `SET NAMES` - so you know in future the main consideration is the database encoding and the `client_encoding` setting.

Comment: Please show the output of `SELECT current_setting('client_encoding') AS cl_enc, current_setting('server_encoding') AS srv_enc;` when run by your application. You should also show your PostgreSQL and PHP versions.

Comment: hello postgres 9.1, there is 'no' real php installed on server. Its tomcat and php portlet is running by quercus. output is ` cl_enc | srv_enc
--------+---------
 UTF8   | UTF8
`

Comment: Maybe you can find the solution in this article? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/multibyte.html

Comment: UTF is UTF i had never this problem with mysql. I know before it comes to postgresql db its normal. It displays normal. I am going to try put those chars to DB with psql right on server and let u know.

Comment: @S.Visser Hey i tried it to add to my connect but no help

Comment: so when i tried it to add it manually the following happened : `ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xf36fb5e8
`. So it looks like DB looks on outside for ASCII???? I dont understand. What is between frontend and database? Why is it "posting" to db like ASCII and not like UTF?

Comment: OK this is what i get from database. `insert INTO podujatia (nazov) VALUES ('ó');
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xf327293b` i really dont know. Why php utf knows it and when it comes to DB it says invalid for UTF8? im going to resave it again all in notepad++ to utf8 but i did it so many times...

Comment: Seems to have been modified and reposted as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900759/postgres-foreign-languages#15900759, so close-voting this question.