# POSTGRES foreign languages

Tags: postgresql

I have problem with directly inserting foreign characters like "ó,č,ĕ,ř" characters into database. dont working even with my php frontend to be sure there is no transformation or other encoding. So im using logged in psql directly and here is my setup :

```
server_encoding
-----------------
UTF8
(1 row)
```

and

```
client_encoding
-----------------
UTF8
(1 row)
```

database is :

```
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |  
   my_db   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

So i guess there should be no problem.

I created this :

```
CREATE TABLE test (a text);
```

and now i want to insert some text

```
INSERT INTO TEST (a) ('ó');
```

And there is a message :

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xf327293b
```

Is there anyone who can help me please? it looks like it was ignoring my input encoding or i really dont know.

EDIT :

my terminal configuration

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

EDIT2:

```
my_db=# \encoding
UTF8
```

EDIT3: psql from file

file

```
file -bi test
text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

execute

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'Ăł'"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO tes (a) ('Ăł');
```

EDIT4:

```
set client_encoding='latin1';
```

this works in psql but i need it to works with utf8. I know its possible i used this setup everytime with mysql databases and it works like a charm.

My jdbc driver needs it to be UTF8.

EDIT5:

Here is what am i doing here : [click me](http://www.forumhistoriae.sk/podujatia)

Before its stored i can see it - so php is working fine  - , but after then when i read it from DB i cant see it. Thats because i moved closer to DB into psql to see whats going on. It looks like maybe server issue. Is it possible server can't handle that characters?

EDIT6:

Tomcat config

```
 -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

URI encoding is set to UTF8 too. Where can be that problem? :(

Comment: How did you enter the INSERT command? Is your terminal encoding set to UTF-8?

Comment: (it's not; F3 is ó in ISO8859-1, the bytes after it are `');`. So you're sending the command in the wrong encoding)

Comment: try entering `\encoding` in the psql shell and see the output; something odd is going on.

Comment: hey. i've edited it again.

Comment: Don't speak of "foreign languages", just say non-ASCII. The concept of "foreign" is relative and restrictive.

Comment: Previously posted as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897015/database-stores-strange-characters (this copy is a greatly improved version of the older question)

Comment: @leonbloy Not to mention vaguely offensive to the fairly large proportion of people here who're "foreign" under that definition. World != USA+UK+AU (I'm in AU). Even here it's v.frustrating seeing people writing "Resume" because they don't know how to type Résumé, cafe for café, etc

Comment: i get it but thats not the point. Those arent special characters , those are foreign characters. Not of all for me cuz im from slovakia but some are. Also we had a normal declared "foreign words" so i dont know why are you so angry. And yes World != USA/UK/AU but english is international language here so thats the point.

Comment: Not angry, don't worry. More frustrated by how hard technology makes it to use a variety of languages and scripts well. Please disregard.

Comment: ofc. Esperanto ftw :)

Comment: What terminal are you using? gnome-terminal? xterm? ...other? Sounds like your locale environment is set to utf-8 but your terminal is actually operating in latin-1 or similar.

Comment: @Craig putty i think its xterm emulator

Answer (score 2):

If your shell is in latin1 encoding, as it appears from the comments, this will fix it:

```
set client_encoding = 'latin1';
```

If you don't want to change the client's system encoding you can change the default in `postgresql.conf`

```
client_encoding = latin1
```

Or change PHP's default character encoding:

```
default_charset = "utf-8";
```

Do it also in the Apache, or whatever http server you are using, config:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Comment: hey yeah. insert worked. But tell me please how is it possible to mix 2 encodings? But when im trying to post it from php its still the same issue. Wrong chars are displayed. should i query "set client_encoding=latin1" by every query now? Or will it stay set generally?

Comment: @Martin It looks like you are running both client and server in the same system. Change your system(s) encoding to utf8. Otherwise yes, you will have to set the encoding at each connection.

Comment: I think i dont get it. My situation is following : server running liferay. I have integrated php portlet [click link](http://www.forumhistoriae.sk/podujatia) and i can add some things. But after i add them i can display them correctly in phpportlet -before reading them from db-. After then database transform them into some of AA funny characters. PHP files UTF-8 encoded

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I tried it but it must work with UTF8 because as i said my jdbc driver wants it. I think there is a way to make it work UTF-8 UTF-8. As far as i know UTF8 supports every language so 'ó' shouldnt make a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just another debugging test (I still think it's a terminal thing): can  you write the insert statement in a UTF-8 encoded file and try to run the command from the file? Eg:

```
psql my_db -U postgres -f <utf8-encoded-file>
```

If this works fine then it's back to the terminal somehow ...

Comment: it looks like i cant use those chars in ubuntu shell but i can in psql. So i made file using notepad++ (utf-8 encoded) transfered it to server and executed. EDIT 3 says what happened.

Comment: Your results for EDIT 3 could be explained by the fact you're missing the `VALUES` keyword, irrespectively of the encoding. Try `INSERT INTO tes (a) VALUES ('Ăł');`

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments you're using PuTTY, which defaults to latin-1. You need to configure PuTTY to use UTF-8. Just setting the server locale won't do any good unless your PuTTY encoding matches what the environment claims the encoding is.

Open PuTTy. Under the Window settings heading choose the Translation sub-heading. Set "Remote character set" to "utf-8". In the Fonts sub-tab make sure you are using a font with reasonable Unicode coverage. Then, in the Session menu type a name into the "saved settings" text entry box and type "save" to save your settings as a profile. You can override the "Default Settings" profile by selecting it and setting Save, but this will affect all future connections and new profiles so it may cause confusion if you use other servers that aren't utf-8.

(These instructions are  based on my PuTTY on Fedora 18; there may be some differences in UI details in the recent Windows versions. If in doubt, search for how to set PuTTY to use utf-8.)

Comment: Thanks. But nevertheless i dont care about putty. data comes from php portlet which is inserting it to database. So this is the issue. Putty is just a tool for remote control for me. See EDIT5 please. But i appreciate any help. If u can see i can hardcode it. Just before insert i created hardcoded encoding to utf8 code like #xxxx; and this works. But i dont know where the problem is. Why isnt it done automatically when UTF-8 is on both sides?

Comment: @MartinFric You're using `psql` via `Putty` for diagnostics right? Then unless your encoding setting is correct in PuTTY you're testing with the wrong inputs and outputs.

Comment: Ok u were right. Putty uses latin-2. So no it works normally when i want to insert this string to db directly. S i think i must move to inserting and how are data posted to DB from server. In EDIT6 u can see my tomcat configuration.

Comment: @MartinFric I'm losing the thread of this, it's getting tangled with too many different things. PuTTY, remote access, terminals, client encodings, appservers.... We can't really debug the whole app. At this point all I can really suggest is that you create a self-contained compileable test case that demonstrates the problem, one that can just be downloaded and run after a simple .sql script to set up the database. Cut the code down to the absolute minimum that demonstrates the problem. In the process you will usually discover what's causing the problem and how to fix it.